# CryptoLocker master key

Tags: cryptography, ransomware

I am struggling to understand how it is possible to decrypt files encrypted by the TeslaCrypt ransomware using the [master key their creators provided](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/teslacrypt-shuts-down-and-releases-master-decryption-key/).

As far as I know, ransomware encrypts files using a symmetric cryptosystem, and then encrypts the key using an asymmetric encryption scheme. How does one decrypt the affected files by having the master key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a very abstract level: malware on each victim's machine in addition to encrypted AES keys used to encrypt the files, stores an encrypted copy of the private key required to decrypt them. This copy itself is encrypted with the public key of the attacker and can be decrypted with the attacker's private key (called "master key" in the article).

I will try to rephrase Kaspersky's article [TeslaCrypt 2.0 disguised as CryptoWall](https://securelist.com/blog/research/71371/teslacrypt-2-0-disguised-as-cryptowall/) in a more verbose way.

For the sake of simplicity I will skip the fact that each file can be encoded with different AES key. Also actual implementation might differ (particularly more data can be sent to the attacker and some steps are performed on the attacker's side). Anyway the answer aims to explain how the master password-scheme works:

---

At first victim has only `attacker-public-key` (embedded in the malware).
Attacker has `attacker-private-key`.

1. malware creates a new BTC address with a `victim1-BTC-public-key` (to send BTC) and a `BTC-private-key` (to withdraw BTC)
2. malware uses `attacker-public-key` and and `victim1-BTC-private-key` as the input to ECDH which generates an `encryption-key-1`
3. malware XORs `victim1-BTC-private-key` with the `encryption-key-1`, stores the result as `encrypted-victim1-BTC-private-key`, forgets `encryption-key-1`
4. malware sends the `victim1-BTC-private-key` to the attacker and deletes it

Victim owns: `attacker-public-key`, `victim1-BTC-public-key`, `encrypted-victim1-BTC-private-key`.
Attacker owns: `attacker-private-key`, `victim1-BTC-private-key`.

Next malware starts to encrypt files:

1. malware generates a key-pair and uses the private key as AES encryption key, so the pair consists of `victim1-AES-key` (`victim1-keypair-private-key`) and `victim1-keypair-public-key`
2. malware uses the `victim1-BTC-public-key` and `victim1-AES-key` as an input to ECDH which generates an `encryption-key-2`
3. malware XORs `AES-key` with the `encryption-key-2`, stores the result as encrypted-AES-key, forgets encryption-key-2

Victim owns: `attacker-public-key`, `victim1-BTC-public-key`, `encrypted-victim1-BTC-private-key`, `victim1-keypair-public-key`, `encrypted-victim1-AES-key`.
Attacker owns: `attacker-private-key`, `BTC-victim1-private-key`.

---

Now victim paid the ransom and attacker releases a key to decrypt the files:

1. attacker reveals `BTC-victim1-private-key`
2. malware uses `BTC-victim1-private-key` and `victim1-keypair-public-key` as an input to ECDH which calculates `encryption-key-2` (the same as above)
3. malware XORs `encrypted-victim1-AES-key` with the `encryption-key-2` which gives `victim1-AES-key`
4. malware decrypts the file(s) with `victim1-AES-key`

No other victim can do anything using `BTC-victim1-private-key`.

---

Attacker decides to release the master key:

1. attacker reveals the `attacker-private-key`
2. malware uses `attacker-private-key` and `victim1-BTC-public-key` as the input to ECDH which generates an `encryption-key-1` (the same as above)
3. malware XORs `encrypted-victim1-BTC-private-key` with the `encryption-key-1`, stores the result as `victim1-BTC-private-key`
4. malware uses `BTC-victim1-private-key` and `victim1-keypair-public-key` as an input to ECDH which calculates `encryption-key-2`
5. malware XORs `encrypted-victim1-AES-key` with the `encryption-key-2` which gives `victim1-AES-key`
6. malware decrypts the file(s) with `victim1-AES-key`

In the latter scenario any victim can use the `attacker-private-key` first to derive the `victim*-BTC-private-key` then `victim*-AES-key`.

Comment: question, why would attacker release private key?

Comment: @Irhala I'm not sure I understand the question. Because the developer designed it so.